# Avoid blank spaces in textbox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, textbox

I want to prevent a user from entering blank spaces into a username textbox.I would be very grateful to the person,if anyone answered

Comment: I am doing asp.net using c#.net

Answer (score 2):

Use Javascript code as below:

```
<input type="text" name="myText" onKeypress="if (event.keyCode == 32) event.returnValue = false;"/>
```

tested in `Internet Explorer`

Answer (score 1):

you have to use something in javascript or jquery to avoid it. 
I suggest you a Jquery pluglin, my favorite one is that:

http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/

Comment: Of course, you will have to prevent again in server side for security reasons.
them you would use something like: 

MyTextBox.Text = MyTextBox.Text.Replace(" ", String.Empty);

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('INPUT[type=text]').keypress(function(e) {

                   if (window.event) 
                       keycode = window.event.keyCode;
                   else if (e) 
                       keycode = e.which;
                   else return true;

                   if ((keycode == 32) ) //Space KeyCode
                   {
                       return false;
                   }
                   else {
                       return true;
                   }

               });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `FilteredTextBoxExtender` control from `AjaxControlToolkit`. It will ease your application's maintenance if you need to change or add other forbidden characters some day.

> See example here: [FilteredTextBox Sample](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx)